# custom segue with cross disolve in UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, ios, uistoryboard, segue

In my application there is a UITabbarController, against every tab there is UINavgationController and a list of view in the navigation controller.

I want to change the style of push with Modal->Cross Dissolve but when i do this it breaks the relation with the navigationbar and tabbar and does not show any bar.

How can this be solved?

Comment: You can define your own segues. It's not what you want (which is why this is a comment) but this project implements it's own segues. https://github.com/chrismiles/FancySegue

Comment: i dont want to use libraries, i was hoping there may be any way to subclass uistorryboardsegue and override just the animation. so it remain related with the navigation and tab bar

Comment: is it possible this way?